# HTML5 sessionStorage limits?

Tags: html, web-storage, sessionstorage

A few questions regard HTML5's sessionStorage:

- Does the 5MB limit on localStorage include sessionStorage? (ie. is it really a 5MB limit on the WebStorage API)
- If not does sessionStorage have a maximum size limit similar to localStorage?

I found this site http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/ in another SO questions, I'm wondering if the data is still relevant?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Does the 5MB limit on localStorage include sessionStorage? (Answer: **NO**)
2. is it really a 5MB limit on the WebStorage API (Answer: **NO**; [Supported By](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-localstorage) )
3. does sessionStorage have a maximum size limit similar to localStorage? (Answer: **NO**; [Supported By](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-localstorage) )

Hope I answered all your questions in a simplified manner. Here is a particularly informative section for you:

> **QUOTAS**
>
> You can imagine the chaos if any website was allowed to
>   populate unsuspecting hard drives with gigabytes of data! Thus,
>   browsers impose limits on storage capacity. When your app attempts to
>   exceed that limit, the browser will typically show a dialog to let the
>   user confirm the increase. You might expect the browser to enforce a
>   single limit for all storage an origin can use, but the major browsers
>   are actually enforcing limits separately for each storage mechanism.
>   This may change in the future, but for now, you should think of the
>   browser as maintaining a 2-D matrix, with "origin" in one dimension
>   and "storage" in the other. For example, "http://abc.example.com" is
>   allowed to store up to 5MB of Web Storage, 25MB of Web SQL Database
>   Storage, and forbidden to use Indexed Database. Another welcome
>   enhancement in this area would be user interfaces to let users view
>   and control how much space they have allocated for each origin. There
>   are also environments where the user can see upfront how much storage
>   will be used, e.g. in the case of the Chrome Web Store, when a user
>   installs an app, they will be prompted upfront to accept its
>   permissions, which include storage limits. One possible value is
>   "unlimited_storage".

The above text taken from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/

Comment: That's what the spec says and it's definitely helpful to know... but in practice real browsers have limits. Chrome's appears to be 2.5MB.

Comment: Thanks ELI for that.. :)

Comment: This is why just posting links is a terrible idea, all dead.